# Calling a function with keyword params

Tags: python, syntax

(I really can't come up with a better title!)

I've got a set of functions:

```
def foo(bar, baz)
def spam(blah, etc, woof)
```

and a [Namespace](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace) object which includes the function name and function-specific params, e.g. `args=(fun=foo, baz=111, baz=222)`. How do I call the function and pass params to it? Like this, but nicer:

```
 x = vars(args)
 fun = x['fun']
 del x['fun']
 fun(**x)
```

(I'm looking for a nice one-line solution).

Comment: What is `args=(fun=foo, baz=111, baz=222)`? Maybe you just provide more context...

Comment: What's wrong with your solution? It's simple and readable.

Comment: @glglgl: added the doc link to the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `aDict` is a dictionary with function name under `"fun"` key and other arguments you could try:

`aDict.pop("fun")(**aDict)`

Comment: Nice, but I initially have a Namespace, not dict.

Comment: @thg435: then do `aDict = vars(args); aDict.pop("fun")(**aDict)`. Does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want `x['fun'](**x)`?

That will work as long as your function takes a `**kwargs` argument. If not, you will have to do something to slice the entries you want out of the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking for, but this should give you similar results:

```
def callback(fun, *args, **kwargs):
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
```

and then you can call it like that:

```
callback(some_func, 'a', 'b', c=10, d=123)
```

which will in turn invoke:

```
some_func('a', 'b', c=10, d=123)
```

Comment: You posted it without `args`, and even with `args` it is hard to say what your "_namespace_" object really is.

Answer (score 0):

I will not provide you with a solution but here is a hint:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def g(a, b, c=3):
pass

>>> inspect.getargs(g.func_code)
Arguments(args=['a', 'b', 'c'], varargs=None, keywords=None)
```

So now you know the arguments and their order and you may use the Namespace object effectively.
Note: This may only be possible in C-Python!

to call the function use this:

```
>>> arguments = (1, 2, 3)
>>> keywords = {}
>>> g(*arguments, **keywords)
```

Have a nice day!

Comment: `I will not provide you with a solution` - why?

Comment: There is the Arguments class given and how to call the function with arguments flexibly. This is sufficient to create your own solution.